# Instantiated class in Kotlin still possibly null. Why?

Tags: kotlin

Question is simple:
In Kotlin, when I instantiate a fragments `arguments` with a `Bundle()`, the system still needs the arguments object to be reassured with `!!`. The `arguments` should be definitely not null by now, right? So why is that needed?

Here is the code:

```
private fun openPinCodeFragment(mode: PinView.Mode) {
    currentFragment = PinCodeFragment()
    currentFragment?.run {
        arguments = Bundle()
        arguments!!.putSerializable(MODE, mode)
    }
    openFragment(currentFragment)
}
```

If I remove the `!!` then:

[image]

Comment: What IDE is that ? Eclipse ?

Comment: Android Studio. Is anyone still developing Android in Eclipse?

Comment: [Yup](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#technology-development-environments-and-tools-mobile-developers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting the value of a variable which was defined outside of this scope (the declaration of `arguments` is not visible in your code).

No matter what you assign, it could have been changed by the time code execution reaches the next line to a `null` value by another `Thread`, that's why you have to use the `!!` here. I'd suggest defining `arguments` either in local scope with `val` or making it non-nullable in its definition.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `arguments` is of Bundle? type, this means that it can be either Bundle or null.

Instead of using an if to check whether it is null, like you would to in Java, the operators `!!` and `?` were introduced.

For example if you want your code to be correct without using `!!` you could add:

```
if (arguments != null) {
   arguments.putSerializable(MODE, mode)
}
```

Using these operators you have the following flexibility:

1. `!!` - you tell the compiler that the value cannot be null, it will throw error otherwise;
2. `?` - you don't care that much, if it is not null then it will access method and might return result, otherwise the result of such call is null and no action is made.

Comment: OP declared `arguments` as `Bundle` and not `Bundle?`

Comment: there is no declaration of arguments variable in his snippet of code, he just assigned `Bundle` object to the variable.

Comment: Oh right, I mismatched initialization and declaration